# Partial specialization in c++ template : template parameter not deducible

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The below code works fine :

```
template<typename T, int n> 
class Fib {};

template<typename T,int n>
class Fib<T*,n> {};
```

But the below code shows error as:

> Error : template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:

```
 template<typename T, int n> 
 class Fib {};

 template<typename T,int n>
 class Fib<T*,0> {};
```

Can you explain the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: I guess you know already, but the specialization should read `template<typename T> class Fib<T*,0> { };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are just missing the right syntax for the partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, int n> 
 class Fib {

 };

 template<typename T>
 class Fib<T*,0> {

 };
```

The first parameter on the template is type, while the second is just a constant value.